# Как правильно изолировать бизнес-логику в Django

Tags: python, django, ооп

Допустим, есть какая-то вьюха, в которой должно быть много логики. Чтобы не писать ее в самом классе `ProductView`, я хотел бы создать служебный класс, например, `ProductService` и вынести всю логику в него.

```
class ProductView(View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._product_service = ProductService()
```

В реализации логики мне будет постоянно нужен объект текущего запроса. Поэтому, было бы хорошо передать его в конструктор класса `ProductService` и использовать внутри как атрибут класса.

Проблема в том, что на момент создания `ProductService` в конструкторе вьюхи, `ProductView` еще не имеет объекта `self.request`. Поэтому приходится передавать его потом при вызове каждого метода сервиса. Можно ли как-то это обойти и передать запрос в класс сервиса только один раз?

Comment: Может, Вам стоит создать свой [`Mixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/mixins/)?

Comment: @nomnoms12 mixin это конечно хорошо. Но мне бы хотелось понять как делают такие штуки с сервисами. Несколько раз такое слышал, но не могу понять как реализвать это в такой ситуации.

Comment: Вопрос выглядит слишком общим, можно сказать, философским. Я слышал про распространенный в Django подход, что во вьюхах как можно меньше логики, а вот про модели ограничения нет, многие так и делают. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/misc/design-philosophies/#include-all-relevant-domain-logic про философию в документации есть раздел. А еще вот https://apirobot.me/posts/where-to-put-business-logic-in-django полезным может оказаться материал.

Comment: А еще вот и вот https://qna.habr.com/q/640113, https://habr.com/en/post/213875/. Похоже на попытку переложить функции поисковых систем на участников сообщества, простите.

Comment: Вопрос очень хороший и важный, лишь хотел сказать, что правильного подхода может не существовать и это выльется в обсуждение

Comment: @mrEvgenX мой вопрос очень конкретный на самом деле :) Как передать `request` в мой класс сервиса. Про то какие существуют подходы и какой из них лучше, я как раз таки спорить не собирался

Comment: Неправильно воспринял, сильно было похоже на то

Comment: В методе `dispatch()` пробовали? Почему-то мне кажется, что это должно сработать.

Comment: Привязывать логику к запросу не очень красиво, так как это ограничивает гибкость. В некоторых случаях запроса может не быть — например, GitHub позволяет писать комментарии через электронную почту, и в письмах никакого http-запроса разумеется нет, а логику-то выполнять всё равно нужно. Или интегрированный с сайтом Telegram-бот тоже может добавить проблем от отсутствия «классического» запроса.

Comment: @andreymal ну конкретно в моем случае запрос должен быть обязательно. Мне нужно брать из запроса в логику параметры и каждый раз передавать его между всеми методами сервиса напряжно и некрасиво. А так он лежит себе в `self` и все.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров если под параметрами подразумеватся словарь из GET или POST запроса, то можно просто вытащить этот самый словарь, а таскать запрос при этом необязательно

Comment: @andreymal да, это хороший совет, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать это в методе `setup`:

```
class ProductView(View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._product_service = None

    def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().setup()
        self._product_service = ProductService(request)
```